# Is this a typo? Defoe's Robinson Crusoe

Tags: semi-modals

You can see on google books that Defoe's Robinson Crusoe has these two sentences depending on the issue of the book. Which one is correct in your opinion?

> 1 And it is scarce credible what inexpressible labor everything was
> done with, especially the bringing piles out of the woods , and
> driving them into the ground; for I made them much bigger than I
> **need to have done.**
>
> 2 And it is scarce credible what inexpressible labor everything was
> done with, especially the bringing piles out of the woods , and
> driving them into the ground; for I made them much bigger than I
> **needed to have done.**

Comment: _Needed_ would seem to be more logical, since the narrative describes a past situation.

Comment: That's what I thought. Or it could be "need not have done"